# ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (115)

Tags: mysql, mysql-connection

I wanted to connect to memsql but when I try i wasn't able to connect , I get error as:

```
mysql -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --prompt="memsql> "
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (115)
```

Even for the local host I get the same error
when I try to install:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package mysql-client is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package mysql-server is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'mysql-server' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'mysql-client' has no installation candidate
```

Suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: I think my mysql got replaced with Mariadb , i don't know how to replcae it back with mysql

Comment: Can you describe why you can't run MariaDB instead of MySQL?

Comment: What if remove `-h 127.0.0.1` of the sentence? being `localhost` should be avoided.

Comment: I wanted to connect to memsql whic is by default mysql. I don't know how mariadb works with it

Comment: I tried ```mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)``` still i get error

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.18-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2